# Loop does not iterate over last substring. (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, loops, data-structures

Hi and thanks in advance!

The first loop never iterates over the last number of my input string, thus never entering by base case to add on the last item into the **max** obj.

Task: Given a list of integers find the mode and the frequency of the mode. The mode in a list of numbers is the value that occurs the most often. If no number in the list is repeated, then there is no mode for the list.

- Input: `1, 2, 3, 6, 10, 3, 5, 6, 3, 3`
- Output: `Mode = 3, Frequency of mode = 4`

```
function countOccurances(str) {

    // if str is empty
    if (str.length === 0) {
        return null
    }

    // if str is of length 1
    if (str.length === 1) {
        console.log('only 1:', str)
        return str
    }

    let sub1
    let sub2
    let max = {}
    let currentMax = 0
    let maxChar

    // Loop through string
    for (let i=0; i<str.length; i++) {  
        console.log('incoming str: ', str)

        // if there is no comma, and index is at the end of the string
        if (str[i] != ',' && i == str.length-1) {
            console.log('base')
            if (str in max) {
                max[sub1]++
            } else {
                max[sub1] = 1
            }

            break
        }

        // If the char is a comma, substring the two sides
        // update str with remaining string (sub2) and reset index of loop
        if (str[i] == ',') {
            sub1 = str.substring(0, i)
            sub2 = str.substring(i+2)

            str = sub2
            i=0
            console.log('outgoing str: ', str)
            // Update occurance of string inside max obj
            if (sub1 in max) {
                max[sub1]++
            } else {
                max[sub1] = 1
            }
        }   
    }

    // Loop max obj to find key, value pair with highest occurance 
    for (char in max) {
        if (max[char] > currentMax) {
            currentMax = max[char]
            maxChar = char
        }
    }

    return max
}

countOccurances('1, 2, 3, 6, 10, 3, 5, 6, 3, 3, 1')
```

Comment: `if (str in max)` is that a typo? Should it be `sub1`? And wouldn't it be easier to use [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)?

Comment: You should limit the code to the part that doesn't do what expected, to avoid us debugging a long code. Side remark: what if you input a single number > 9?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp yes split() would be easier, but I'm purposely trying to use a few string methods as I reasonably can. For no other purpose than to challenge me.

Comment: @Éric it hits the top level base case.

Answer (score 0):

For this input it works fine:

```
countOccurances('1, 2, 3, 6, 10, 3, 5, 6, 3, 3, 1,');
```

Or extend the "reached end of number":

```
if (str[i] === ',' || i === str.length-1) {  ...
```

Quick fix: add a ',' at the end of the incoming string.

A more robust way is to work on an number array:

```
var numbers = '1, 2, 3, 6, 10, 3, 5, 6, 3, 3, 1'.split(',');
```

or:

```
var numbers = '1, 2, 3, 6, 10, 3, 5, 6, 3, 3, 1'.split(',').map(s => parseInt(s, 10));
```

Comment: Thanks Marc. However, if we left the input as is, how do you think I could adjust my loop to incorporate the last number?

Comment: Is this is not an option for you?    str = str + ',';   Anyway: no one would do this. Split the input. It's more robust and much more performant.

Comment: if (str[i] == ','  ||  i === str.length-1) {

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be too much commingling of code in the `for` loop, plus it's usually not a good practice to tinker with the loop variable inside the loop... If you're looking to perform the split of the string with a basic `for` loop, suggest something along the following lines...

```
let values = [];
let begin = 0;
for (let i = 0; i <= str.length; i++) {
  if ( i == str.length || str[i] == ',' ) {
    values.push( parseInt( str.substring( begin, i ) ) );
    begin = i + 1;
  }
}
```

...with the `values` array holding the results.

Hope this helps...